# Run time Error 424 object required - public key encryption macro

Tags: excel, vba, encryption

We are currently trying to get the encryption macro to work on multiple cells throughout the workbook, I have a lot going on with some of these cells so I am open to anything to make this flow better. Currently, the macro is under our finalize form button. This is the coding on sheet 1, the function code is under "this workbook"

When we try running this under other worksheet_selectionchange(ByVal target As Range) code, it doesn't allow the text box (got_focus) code to run on the cell. 
I've tried changing the location of the code whether its in its own sub or being called to with a button and I'm unable to get this to correct itself. the cell that is in range is merged and would be ("B23:D23"), but making that change didn't change my debug error.

```
Private Sub FINALIZEBTN_Click()
    Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult
    response = MsgBox("Have you completed the form in full?", vbYesNo)
    If response = vbYes Then
        MsgBox "Do not forget to save and submit this form"
    ElseIf response = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "Please review and complete the form in full"
        Exit Sub
    End If

Dim searchRange     As Excel.Range
Dim cell            As Variant
Dim RegEx           As Object

Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

With RegEx
    .Pattern = "[^ :@a-zA-Z0-9&\-]+"
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
End With

Set searchRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B18:E52") '// Change as required

    For Each cell In searchRange.Cells
        If RegEx.Test(cell) Then cell.value = RegEx.Replace(cell.value, "")
        cell.value = UCase(cell.value)
    Next cell

Set searchRange = Nothing
Set RegEx = Nothing


'ENCRYPTION MACRO

    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("B23")


Dim publicKey As String
    publicKey = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>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</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>" 'put entire xml string here

  If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       If VarType(Range(target.Address).value) <> 8204 Then
           If Len(Range(target.Address).value) < 256 Then 'making sure that encry sting isnt previously encrypted
              Range(target.Address).value = ThisWorkbook.Encrypt(publicKey, CStr(Range(target.Address).value))
               Range(target.Address).HorizontalAlignment = -4108 'XLALIGNCENTER
            End If
       Else
    Range(target.Address).HorizontalAlignment = -4131 'XLALIGNLEFT
        End If
       Application.EnableEvents = True
 End If
End Sub
```

The line

`If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(target.Address)) Is Nothing Then` causes the run-time error 424 object required pop up.

Comment: You're intersecting with `target` but `target` is never defined or set?

Comment: So ``Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("B23")`` isn't doing that?

Comment: Sure, that's `KeyCells`, I see that, but you still haven't defined or set `target`

Comment: So I need so have something that states `set target as keycells`?

Comment: If `target` and `KeyCells` are always just going to be the same, why are you referencing `target` at all?  Just remove the Intersect and replace all references to `target` with `KeyCells` instead.

Comment: Am I removing Application? or doing something else there?

Comment: the code now reads ```If Not Application(KeyCells, Range(KeyCells.Address)) Is Nothing Then
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       If VarType(Range(KeyCells.Address).value) <> 8204 Then
           If Len(Range(KeyCells.Address).value) < 256 Then 'making sure that encry sting isnt previously encrypted
              Range(KeyCells.Address).value = ThisWorkbook.encrypt(publicKey, CStr(Range(target.Address).value))
               Range(KeyCells.Address).HorizontalAlignment = -4108 ``` and gives a new error of "compile error: wrong number of arguements or invalid property assignment"

Comment: Ok, it's becoming clear to me that you're trying to stitch in code from what looks like a `Worksheet_Change` event that you found somewhere (either online or from code elsewhere in your workbook), but you don't know how to modify it.  Unfortunately, this isn't really a forum for fixing it or doing it for you.  However, I will say that what you need to do will look something like this: `If VarType(KeyCells.Value) <> 8204 Then`...

Comment: Yes, I noted that in the OP. We were having problems with other macros running when this was done as a worksheet_change. Our audit team provided us with the code for the encryption and i was trying to get it to link to a button to see if that would eliminate the runtime-errors. Ive used this forum for assistance with coding so if that means showing me how then it is what it is. I will try your VarType method to see if that works. Thanks!

Comment: The VarType didn't work.